# C# datagrid is not updating itemsource when get added

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

when typing in the textbox and click "Add Employee", i want it to update and display to the datagrid, i've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and RelayCommand. what am i missing that's not populating the data. thanks in advance
here is my model

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Pedicure { get; set; }
    public int Tip { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

this is my ViewModel

```
    List<EmployeeModel> employeeModel = new List<EmployeeModel>() { };

    private ICommand _addEmployeeCommand;

    public ICommand AddEmployeeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _addEmployeeCommand ?? (_addEmployeeCommand = new RelayCommand(x => { AddNewEmployee(); }));
        }
    }

    public List<EmployeeModel> Employee
    {
        get { return employeeModel; }
        set
        {
            if(value != employeeModel)
            {
                employeeModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Employee");
            }
        }
    }

    private string employeeName;
    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get { return employeeName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != employeeName)
            {
                employeeName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeName");
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddNewEmployee()
    {
        Employee.Add(new EmployeeModel { Name = EmployeeName });
    }
```

here is my View

```
        <TabItem Header="Employee">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employee}">
                </DataGrid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Name: "/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding EmployeeName}"
                 Width="40"
                 Height="15"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Button Content="Add"
            Command="{Binding AddEmployeeCommand}"
                Height="20"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Use  `ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel>` which will notify UI when items are added

Comment: that worked...thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I pluralized the name `Employee` to `Employees` in this answer for future readers)*

The problem is with the `Source` of the `DataGrid`

Bear in mind that `OnPropertyChanged("Employees")` only notifies about the changes made to the `Employees` and is not responsible for any changes made within `Employees`.

To be clear, it only works when you do `employeeModels = new List<EmployeeModel>()`
And won't be called when `Employees.Add(employee)`

Hopefully WPF has its own `ObservableCollection` type that will take care of that:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>;
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get { return _employees; } }
```